# Different CSS file for different steps in AJAX form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with some steps. All steps are changing with AJAX. All the things are working good. But now I have a question. I want to load different CSS file for different steps. Like when the form is on **step1** then `step1.css` will load and when form is on **step2** then `step2.css` will load.

Is this possible to change css file with changing AJAX?

Hope I have explained well my problem.

Comment: Don't change the stylesheet itself. Instead put the steps in containing elements with a class on. Then you can style the contents based on that class. For example `.step1 input { ... }` `.step2 input { ... }`

Comment: You actually can not as once something loaded it will be there until you reload the whole page. You just can only override the CSS.

Comment: @UllasHunka not actually true, stylesheets can be `disabled` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled (Probably not to recommend in this case here, but that’s a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for the very useful information. I was not aware with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
if (!document.getElementById(cssId))
{
    var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.id   = cssId;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet.css';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

or Instead you can separate your steps by separating your steps with selectors like wise separate then with you class or ID

Comment: also you can append you css conditionally
$(selector).append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">');

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is possible through JavaScript, But I do strongly recommend against it.

- Every time you insert a new style sheet into the page you force the browser to re-render the page (**performance**)
- Most of the time these new CSS files contain only a small amount of code which is not worth a connection to the server (**speed**)

The preferred way would be to use CSS classes here and load all the CSS rules at once.

```css
.form-step-one span {
  background-color: gray;
}

.form-step-two span {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-step-one">
  <span>Step 1</span>
  <span>Question:</span>
</div>

<div class="form-step-two">
  <span>step 2</span>
  <span>Question:</span>

</div>
```

**Extra Tip:** For more efficiency you need to have a look at Sass and a build tool like Gulp to automate the process and write your CSS rules in different files but load them all into your app in one single merged file.